# Что означают буквы в объявлении JNI функции?

Tags: jni, java

Есть регистрация нативных функций в вызове JNI_OnLoad

```
env->RegisterNatives(cls, methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
```

где `methods` это

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"getVersion", "()I", (void*) GetVersion},
};
```

а `GetVersion`

```
static jint GetVersion(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос в том, что такое строка `"()I"`, по каким правилам она создается и что значит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это дескриптор метода. Он характеризует типы параметров и тип возвращаемого значения.
В общем виде выглядит так: `(param_1_type;param_1_type;...param_1_type)return_type`.

Касательно `I` - это дескриптор примитивного типа int. То есть `()I` - это дескриптор функции без параметров, возвращающей `int`.

Еще несколько примеров:

```
B    byte    
C    char    
D    double  
F    float   
I    int     
J    long    
L<classname>; экземпляр класса <classname>
S    short   
Z    boolean
[    одно изменение массива
```

Подробно про это расписано, разумеется, [в спецификации Java Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/vmspec/2nd-edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1169).